# Как передать PendingIntent в метод, создающий Notification?

Tags: android, java

Пару месяцев назад только начал изучать Java и программирование под Android. Столкнулся с проблемой и вообще не имею представления, в чем может быть дело.

```
  public void onClick(View v){
    intent1 = createIntent("action 1", "extra 1");
    pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    intent2 = createIntent("action 2", "extra 2");
    pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent2, 0);

    sendNotif(101,pendingIntent1);
    sendNotif(201,pendingIntent2);
}
Intent createIntent(String action,String extra){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    intent.putExtra("extra",extra);
    return intent;
}
 void sendNotif(int id,PendingIntent p){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker("Тicker")
            .setContentText("Content"+id)
            .setContentTitle("Title"+id)
            .setProgress(100,20,true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentIntent(p);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    // notification.flags = notification.flags|Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    nm.notify(id,notification);
}
```

Нужно создать два уведомления, метод `sendNotif(int id, PendingIntent p)`, в событии по нажатию я создаю интенты и пендингинтенты, и последние передаю в качестве параметра в мой метод, но вылетает ошибка, и эмулятор просто крашится.

Вот куски в Logcat, где я разобрал только вот эти 2 рядка:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.notify(int, android.app.Notification)' on a null object reference
```

Как я понимаю из `NullPointerException`, он говорит о том, что второй параметр, переданный в метод notify, не связан ни с чем.

P.S. Если вы прочли все это, уже огромное Вам спасибо за потраченные минуты!